# Pyshp appends new fields but not record values to an existing shapefile

Tags: python, csv, shapefile

The problem consists in append columns presented in a .csv file as new fields to an existing shapefile. So, I've used Python and the modules pyshp and csv to, first, copy the content of the original shapefile (geometries and records) and, second, create new fields in this copy and iterate in the respective .csv rows in order to insert on it:

```
import os, sys
import shapefile, csv

from os.path import basename

filename_full = sys.argv[1]
output_full = sys.argv[2]

name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename_full)
output_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(output_full)

filename_dbf =  name + ".dbf"
filename_classified =  name + "_classified.csv"
output_dbf =  output_name + ".dbf"

# reader
myshp = open(filename_full, "rb")
mydbf = open(filename_dbf, "rb")
r = shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp, dbf=mydbf)

# writer
w = shapefile.Writer(r.shapeType)

# copy shapefiles content
w._shapes.extend(r.shapes())
w.records.extend(r.records())
w.fields = list(r.fields)
w.save(output_full)

# add new records from the csv
with open(filename_classified, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')    
     headers = reader.fieldnames
     [w.field(field) for field in headers]     
     for row in reader:            
        w.record(*tuple([row[f] for f in headers])) # <-- insertion in specific fields

w.save(output_full)
```

In the [pyshp page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp), there are a couple of examples. One of them is specific to insertion of rows to a specific field. As follows:

```
>>> w = shapefile.Writer()
>>> w.field('FIRST_FLD','C','40')
>>> w.field('SECOND_FLD','C','40')
>>> w.record('First', 'Line')
>>> w.record(FIRST_FLD='First', SECOND_FLD='Line')
```

but, even indicating the fields, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assigning-shapefile.py", line 68, in <module>
    w.record(*tuple([row[f] for f in headers]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/shapefile.py", line 1040, in record
    record = [recordList[i] for i in range(fieldCount)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/shapefile.py", line 1040, in <listcomp>
    record = [recordList[i] for i in range(fieldCount)]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

and, if we look inside the shapefile, we have something like this:

[QGIS attribute table before and after the code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJTLy.png)

which I concluded that the fields are successful added, but the rows (w.record with the fields name specified) are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using a quite simple approach with osgeo library:

```
# --
# USAGE: 
#       python3 assinging-shapefile.py [input-shapefile] [output-shapefile]
# --
# REQUISITE: 
#   The classification csv file should be edited as a header of classifiers and its labels. The file name is mandatory to be IMAGE_NAME-classified.csv
#   Ex: 
#       Filename: IMAGE_NAME-classified.csv
#       Content: 
#               Random forest, Multilayer-Perc, CRF, SVM
#               vegetation, vegetation, building, vegetation
#               wall, window, window, window 
#               ...
# --

import os, sys
import shapefile, csv

from os.path import basename
from osgeo import ogr

filename_full = sys.argv[1]
output_full = sys.argv[2]

name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename_full)
output_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(output_full)

filename_dbf =  name + ".dbf"
filename_classified =  name + "_classified.csv"
output_dbf =  output_name + ".dbf"

myshp = open(filename_full, "rb")
mydbf = open(filename_dbf, "rb")
r = shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp, dbf=mydbf)
w = shapefile.Writer(r.shapeType)

# copy shapefile
w._shapes.extend(r.shapes())
w.records.extend(r.records())
w.fields = list(r.fields)
w.save(output_full)

# read the csv records
csvRecords = []
csvHeaders = []
with open(filename_classified, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvHeaders = reader.fieldnames  
    for line in reader:
        csvRecords.append(line)

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
infile = driver.Open(output_full, 1)

for classifier in csvHeaders:
    field = ogr.FieldDefn(classifier, ogr.OFTString)
    field.SetWidth(16)

    layer = infile.GetLayer()
    layer.CreateField(field)

cont = 0
for feature in layer:   
    for classifier in csvHeaders:       
        if(feature.GetField(0)!=cont):
            cont += 1

        feature.SetField(classifier, csvRecords[cont][classifier]) 
        layer.SetFeature(feature)           
infile=None
```

which is able (i) to read the csv file (with the columns to be added), (ii) read the shapefile and copy it, (iii) modify the .shp copy by editing each row with a correspondent csv record.